# Stop android emulator from command line jump pop up message

Tags: command-line, android-emulator

So i am start my `Android emulator` from command line using this `command`:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_XL_API_27
```

And when i want to stop i am using this `command`:

```
adb -e emu kill
```

So after this command i have `window message`:

[image]

Any option to disable this `message` >

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-no-snapshot-save` parameter will disable snapshot.

You can check other params available at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#startup-options